# How to propagate data from mod-auth-external authenticator to served page

Tags: apache, http-status-code-401, pam, mod-auth-external

**Background**

In our Apache configuration we use [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external) (previously on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/)) to invoke PAM authentication.

Now there is a request for proper handling of shadow-based password expiration:

1. If password is before warning period Apache should respond with HTTP status code 200. Nothing new here.
2. If password is in warning period (its validity end is near) Apache should respond with HTTP status code 200, but include somehow information about the warning period.
3. If password is in expiration period (it is no longer valid but user can still change it on his own) Apache should respond with HTTP status code 401 and include somehow information about expiration period.
4. If password is beyond expiration period (it is no longer valid and account was locked, administrator must unlock it) Apache should respond with HTTP status code 401 and include somehow information about the locked state.

(There are also corner cases of page missing or some other errors. It is not clear what to do then. But it seems that solving above points would allow to solve those corner cases as well.)

Our PAM authenticator (used through [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external)) is able to differentiate those cases by adjusting return values. That we already have.

The problem is however how to get information from the authenticator to the associated action serving the page (either actual page with 200 status code or 401 error document).

**Current investigations**

It should be noted that there is significant difference between requirement 2 and requirements 3 and 4.

Requirements 3 and 4 alone are somewhat easier because they both involve our [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external) authenticator returning error (access denied). So we only need to know how to get that error code in 401 error page. I even [raised issue](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/issues/21) on that on [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external) page.

Requirement 2 is much more difficult. In that case our authenticator must return 0 (access granted) and still somehow propagate information about the warning to whatever gets served in the end.

**Logs parsing**

Obvious (and ugly) idea is to parse logs. [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external) description on [Google Code Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/wiki/AuthHowTo) mentions that authenticator return value gets written to Apache syslog. Also whatever authenticator prints to standard error stream gets logged as well.

This could be used to pass information from authenticator to some other entities.

The difficulty here is that it is not clear how to do it safely. What to print to be sure that "the other entity" will match properly current request with log entry. Mere URL doesn't seem to be enough since there can be multiple requests for the same URL at the same time. While I don't see anything more useful in what authenticator gets.

Another issue here is that it seems that to be able to parse the logs you have to have some non-trivial code running for "the other entity". And this complicates things further since how should we do it?

**Another idea**

If we could make the authenticator somehow modify "request session" (or whatever, maybe just environment? - I don't know, I'm new to Apache) to add  arbitrary data to it we would be (almost) at home.

Our authenticator would somehow store "password status" and also possibly days remaining to the end of warning/expiration period (if applicable). Then upon serving 401 error page we would retrieve that back and use it to dynamically generate content of the page.

Or even better we would have it stored in session so that the other end could read that data directly. (For cases where it is not simply a browser showing page.)

But so far I fail to see how to do that.

---

Do you have any idea how to meet those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

For over a month I got no answer here. Nor on [GitHub issue](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/issues/21) that I opened for [`mod-auth-external`](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external).

So I ended doing a custom modification to our `mod-auth-external`. I don't like modifying third party software but this one seems dead anyway. And also it turned out we are using pretty old version (2.2.9 which I upgraded to 2.2.11, the last in 2.2.x line). Which already had some customizations anyway.

I explained details of the solution in a comment to my [GitHub issue](https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/issues/21) so I will not repeat them here.

I will however comment on shadow details as they were not mentioned there.

I had two choices: either use [`getspnam`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getspnam) function to retrieve shadow data or to parse messages generated by PAM. First attempts based on [`getspnam`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getspnam) function but in the end I used PAM messages. I didn't have strong reasons for any of those. However I decided to propagate in HTTP response not only shadow status but any PAM message that was generated and so it seemed easier to follow that way.

Comment: it seems you got somewhat angry with this matter. :)

Comment: did you end up adding you fixes to the github repo?

Comment: @MaxBarrass I didn't. I will try to once I will have an opportunity.

Comment: @DavidHayes Saddly no. I tried to publish the change but the `mod-auth-external` changed significantly on their main branch while I ceased to work in the project where this was used in the first place.